# Is the address of a local variable a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, memory-address

In Bjarne Stroustrup's book "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" on p. 267 (Section 10.4.5 Address Constant Expressions), he uses a code example where the address of a local variable is set to a `constexpr` variable. I thought this looked odd, so I tried running the example with g++ version 7.3.0 and was unable to get the same results. Here is his code example verbatim (although slightly abridged):

```
extern char glob;

void f(char loc) {
    constexpr const char* p0 = &glob; // OK: &glob's is a constant
    constexpr const char* p2 = &loc;  // OK: &loc is constant in its scope
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
error: ‘(const char*)(& loc)’ is not a constant expression
```

Is something happening with g++ that I'm not aware of, or is there something more to Bjarne's example?

Comment: Clearly, &loc can't be a constexpr. However, these lines of code don't appear on my kindle version. He does show a constexpr for the address of a "C" style string in a local function. That's legal since these are in global space while loc is an argument on the stack and not constant. Is that example what you are referring to?

Comment: @doug check section 10.4.5 Address Constant Expressions. I'll update the question to make this more clear. Also, my example is abridged

Comment: `char loc` is a locally declared character that is not static. The next time `f()` is called there is no guarantee `loc` will have the same address. 10.4.5 makes that distinction between an address assigned by the linker and those assigned by the compiler. [2013 Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition.pdf](https://github.com/boydfd/books/blob/master/seeing/stalled/2013%20Stroustrup%20-%20The%20C%2B%2B%20Programming%20Language%204th%20Edition.pdf)

Comment: Yup, that's the one. My kindle doesn't have page numbers. His example is legit

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it looks like your version (a pdf) is different from mine (a hard-copy). This must have been a mistake and was updated by the time your pdf was created.

Comment: Yes, I was kinda scratching my head as to where `&glob` came from, but `&loc` was identifiable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good point, I should show that in my question. But yeah, I think this is because our versions are different

Comment: Interesting. Apparently he corrected the edition on my Kindle. Good catch! +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An earlier printing of Bjarne Stroustrup's book "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" on p. 267 has the error outlined in the OP's question. The current printing and electronic copies have been "corrected" but introduced another error described later. It now refers to the following code:

```
constexpr const char* p1="asdf";
```

This is OK because "asdf" is stored in a fixed memory location. In the earlier printing the book errs here:

```
void f(char loc) {
    constexpr const char* p0 = &glob; // OK: &glob's is a constant
    constexpr const char* p2 = &loc;  // OK: &loc is constant in its scope
}
```

However, `loc` is not in a fixed memory location. it's on the stack and will have varying locations depending on when it is called.

However, the current 4th edition printing has another error. This is the code verbatim from 10.5.4:

```
int main() {
    constexpr const char* p1 = "asdf";
    constexpr const char* p2 = p1;      // OK
    constexpr const char* p3 = p1+2;    // error:  the compiler does not know the value of p1
}
```

This is wrong. The compiler/linker does know the value of p1 and can determine the value of `p1+2` at link time. It compiles just fine.

Comment: So, you're saying that Bjarne should not have said that `&loc` will be "OK", right?

Comment: The example code I used in the question is taken verbatim. After looking at @doug's pdf, I think the hard-copy book that I own is incorrect. I think this mistake was updated in later versions.

Comment: Is it the same as this? https://github.com/boydfd/books/blob/master/seeing/stalled/2013%20Stroustrup%20-%20The%20C%2B%2B%20Programming%20Language%204th%20Edition.pdf

Comment: @jackw11111 my version is different from the pdf provided in that link. doug provided a link to the same pdf. My hard-copy and that pdf show different examples for section 10.4.5

Comment: This answer would be a lot clearer if it explicitly stated that the example in the book is wrong.

Comment: @sbecker I agree but can't state the book is wrong because I don't have the book with that error in it. So far only the OP's printing has that error.

Answer (score 9):

It appears that the example from section 10.4.5 provided in my hard-copy of the "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" is incorrect. And so I've concluded that the address of a local variable is not a `constexpr`.

The example appears to have been updated in some pdf versions as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, the "corrected" sample in later printings is also incorrect. `p2+2` is known by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

This answer tries to clarify why the address of a local variable can't be `constexpr` by analysing an example for the x86-64 architecture.

Consider the following toy function `print_addr()`, which displays the address of its local variable `local_var` and call itself recursively `n` times:

```
void print_addr(int n) {
   int local_var{};
   std::cout << n << " " << &local_var << '\n';

   if (!n)
      return; // base case

   print_addr(n-1);  // recursive case
}
```

A call to `print_addr(2)` produced the following output on my x86-64 system:

```
2 0x7ffd89e2cd8c
1 0x7ffd89e2cd5c
0 0x7ffd89e2cd2c
```

As you can see, the corresponding addresses of `local_var` are different for each call to `print_addr()`. You can also see that the deeper the function call, the lower the address of the local variable `local_var`. This is because the stack grows downwards (i.e., from higher to lower addresses) on the x86-64 platform.

For the output above, the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) would look like the following on the x86-64 platform:

```
                |     . . .     |
Highest address ----------------- <-- call to print_addr(2) 
                | print_addr(2) |    
                -----------------
                | print_addr(1) |
                -----------------
                | print_addr(0) | <-- base case, end of recursion
Lowest address  ----------------- Top of the stack
```

Each rectangle above represents the [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME) for each call to `print_addr()`. The `local_var` of each call is located in its corresponding stack frame. Since the `local_var` of each call to `print_addr()` is located in its own (different) stack frame, the addresses of `local_var` differ.

To conclude, since the address of a local variable in a function may not be the same for every call to the function (i.e., each call's stack frame may be located in a different position in memory), the address of such a variable can't be determined at compile time, and therefore can't be qualified as `constexpr`.

Comment: Useful as it clearly shows how local variable addresses are not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to other answers that have pointed out the mistake, C++ standard only allows constexpr pointers to objects of *static-storage duration*, one past the end of such, or `nullptr`. See [[expr.const/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#8) specifically *#8.2*;

It's worth noting that:

- *string-literals* have *static-storage duration*:
- Based on constraints in declaring `extern` variables, they'll inherently have *static-storage duration* or *thread local-storage duration*.

Hence this is valid:

```
#include <string>

extern char glob;
std::string boom = "Haha";

void f(char loc) {
    constexpr const char* p1 = &glob;
    constexpr std::string* p2 = nullptr;
    constexpr std::string* p3 = &boom;
}
```