# Why is my expression not constant expression inside templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

I have a `constexpr` function as:

```
template<class T, class U>
constexpr bool equal(T&& t, U&& u){
    return std::addressof(t) == std::addressof(u);
}
```

Now, if I call this in main. It works as expected and `equal` behaves just like constexpr to produce constant expression.

```
struct bar_t{
    unsigned _tmp;
};

int main(){
    bar_t a{25}, b{32};
    static_assert(equal(a, a)); // Ok Passes;
    static_assert(equal(a, b)); // Ok Fails;
}
```

Now when make that static assert in a template function. Like this:

```
template <class X>
auto Foo(X&& a, X&& b){
    static_assert(equal(a,b)); // Not constant Expression
    // This line says that equal is not constexpr
}
```

Now here is my question:

- Why is this the case at one place it is constexpr at other it is not?
- How do I make it in such a way that it becomes constant expression everywhere?

Comment: Not necessarily for static assertion but any constexpr in general. Also, why would it then work inside main and not in a template function?

Comment: Looking at `Foo`, it doesn't seem like `a` and `b` are necessarily known at compile time.

Comment: @coder3101 'template function' is a red herring, it is the same issue for *any* constexpr function: Function parameters aren't constexpr themselves, as you can always call the function with constexpr and non-constexpr arguments. The constexpr for the function only guarantees: **if** you call the function with all arguments being constexpr, then the result is constexpr as well and will be compiled, otherwise the function is evaluated at run-time just like any other normal function.

Comment: Hm, the function working within `main` is interesting... Related: [constexpr-ness of local varaiables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698844/is-the-address-of-a-local-variable-a-constexpr). According to given answer, it shouldn't have worked for local variables. Either your compiler (which one? which version?) indeed has a bug, or there is some exception for variables within `main`, as location of these cannot change (`main` is *not* re-entrant in C++, calling it explicitly is UB – unlike in C...).