# C++20 Constexpr virtual not compiling

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, constexpr, c++20

Shouldn't this compile under C++20 on the latest versions of GCC and Clang?

I know that it is not yet supported on Visual Studio C++ compiler.

However, according to this list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support it should have worked with no problems on GCC and Clang.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    constexpr virtual ~Base() noexcept = default;

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr virtual int
    get_value() const noexcept = 0;
};

struct Derived
    : Base {
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr virtual int
    get_value() const noexcept override {
        return 5;
    }
};

int
main() {

    constexpr Derived a;
    constexpr Base const & b = a;
    constexpr auto c = b.get_value();

    std::cout << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would that ever make sense? `constexpr` is a compile time feature, while `virtual` only applies at runtime.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with virtual inheritance. You just can't take the address of a local constexpr variable. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bxd7zh). Do you want a language lawyer answer, or will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698844/is-the-address-of-a-local-variable-a-constexpr) suffice?

Comment: But C++20 now allows for constexpr virtual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXJg_XMJFW0

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, virtual is fine with `constexpr` and even `consteval` now :)

Comment: @cigien _O tempora, o mores_ :-D

Comment: @cigien, thanks, it worked and it looks like Visual Studio can also already dispatch constexpr virtual member functions however constexpr virtual destructors aren't yet supported!

Comment: Small note, I misspoke in the previous comment. While it's true, the dupe doesn't apply exactly, though it's the same idea. `a` is not usable as a constant expression when taking a reference to it, if it's a local variable.